# A question on sequences using squeeze theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ ,

$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$.

Given that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=e$.

(i) Show that $b_n-\frac{3}{2n} < a_n < b_n$ for all positive integer $n$.

(ii) Using Squeeze theorem deduce that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=e$.

(i) I have proved the R.H.S of the inequality as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n \right)^n &=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
\end{align}$$

I am unable to get the L.H.S of the inequality using algebraic method.

(ii) From the inequality i got the answer easily by applying squeeze therem.

It is easy to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n-\frac{3}{2n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=e$, hence by squeeze theorem the result $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=e$

Please Help me to get the L.H.S of the inequality.